# URL Rewrite and get the query string of two different vars with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What I'm trying to do is use the same URL with different query strings to go to two different pages.

What I have right now is a URL's that looks like this

`http://mysite.com/embed?a=somestring` and `http://mysite.com/embed?b=somestring`

I need to get a rewrite rule that will redirect both to two different URL's depending on if the query var is a or b

This below works but it matches both URL's and sends it to the one link

```
RewriteRule ^embed$ index.php?page=embeda [QSA]
```

If I do these two it doesn't work and will always match the first one.

```
RewriteRule ^embed$ index.php?page=embeda [QSA]
RewriteRule ^embed$ index.php?page=embedb [QSA]
```

Not sure how to do two different rewriterules for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [RewriteCond directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and examine the `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \ba=
RewriteRule ^embed$ index.php?page=embeda [QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bb=
RewriteRule ^embed$ index.php?page=embedb [QSA]
```

RewriteCond is really just a conditional, an if statement. Note the `\b` bit in the pattern, it's a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). I put it there to make sure it works even if there are other query string parameters before 'b'.

Comment: Thanks but can it be more definite? I might have other URL's with a or b in it so I need it to be more specific in the condition. Anyway to have the condition as \bembed?a=  That doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: Oh, these should only match `embed?a=str` and `embed?b=str`. You see, it's basically "if the query string has a parameter called 'a', then rewrite the URI 'embed' into index.php?page=embeda.". The RewriteCond examines only the query string, while the RewriteRule's pattern (`^embed$`) examines the actual URI (without the query string). If the RewriteRule's pattern doesn't match the requested URI, the rule is skipped, and the second Condition & Rule are evaulated; if those don't match either, nothing happens. Yesh, it's a bit awkward, but that's how it works.

Comment: LOL, yeah it's awkward yet simple. Yep I tested it with different URL's and works as expected. Thanks a lot for the assistance.